# fetch data from mysql table using php ignoring some values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which have a column with name `domain_name`. in `domain_name` column, different values stores like `google.com`, `facebook.com`, `twitter.com` etc.  I try this which is working.

`$query= 'Select * from accountdb WHERE domain_name="twitter.com" order by domain_name ASC';`

But I want to pick that rows which have the values `facebook.com`, `twitter.com` in one query. I try this to achieve but not working.

`$query= 'Select * from accountdb WHERE domain_name="twitter.com" and domain_name="facebook.com" order by domain_name ASC';`

Alterring quotes

`$query= "Select * from accountdb WHERE domain_name='twitter.com' and name='facebook.com' order by domain_name ASC";`

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: why can't you do select * from accountdb   ?

Comment: either use `or` or an `in` clause (`select * from accountdb where domain_name in 'twitter.com', 'facebook.com'`)

Comment: I can't understand mate, what are you saying? @bhanusengar

Comment: are you asking me or bhanu sengar?

Comment: I am saying why didn't you used "select * from accountdb" ?

Comment: @bhanusengar  Are you mean small case `select`?

Comment: use this query " select * from domain_name order by domain_name ASC"

Comment: I use `or` instead of `and` but not working. @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: I want only those row which have `facebook.com` or `twitter.com`. @bhanusengar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And means that both conditions have to be met which will never ever happen. You want domain_name to be either "twitter.com" or "facebook.com". So you have to use `or`

```
$query= 'Select * from accountdb WHERE domain_name="twitter.com" or domain_name="facebook.com" order by domain_name ASC';
```

If you have more than 2 domains to check, best way is to use in.

```
$query= 'Select * from accountdb WHERE domain_name in ("twitter.com","facebook.com","google.com") order by domain_name ASC';
```

Comment: If I want to ignore these these three results query may be?  `$query= 'Select * from accountdb WHERE domain_name!="twitter.com" and domain_name!="facebook.com" and domain_name!="google.com" order by domain_name ASC';`

Comment: Yes. Or you can use not in. `$query= 'Select * from accountdb WHERE domain_name not in ("twitter.com","facebook.com","google.com") order by domain_name ASC';`

Comment: Select * from accountdb WHERE domain_name NOT IN ("twitter.com","facebook.com") ORDER BY domain_name ASC;

Comment: @faisal97 Please mark it as answer if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR`:

```
$query= 'Select * from accountdb WHERE domain_name="twitter.com" OR domain_name="facebook.com" order by domain_name ASC';
```